Deriving the normalization factors of $SU(2)$
In Georgi's book on Lie Algebras in Particle Physics, he makes the following argument to
derive the normalization factors of $SU(2)$. Define
the raising/lowering operators by $J^\pm = (J_1 \pm i J_2)/\sqrt{2}$,
then by the commutation relation of the algebra,
$[J_a, J_b] = i \epsilon_{abc} J_c$, we have that
$[J^+, J^-] = J_3$. This will come in in a second.
Also assume that $|j, \alpha \rangle$ is the highest
$j$ value in the system, so we define $J^+ | j, \alpha \rangle := 0$.
Calling the normalization factors between states
$N_j(\alpha)$ (where $\alpha$ is some parameter
that's going to be eliminated later), we have
\begin{align*}
    N_j (\beta)^* N_j(\alpha) \langle j - 1, \beta | j - 1, \alpha \rangle
    & = \langle j, \beta | J^+ J^- | j, \alpha \rangle\\
    & = \langle j, \beta | [J^+, J^-] | j, \alpha \rangle\\
    & = \langle j, \beta | J_3 | j, \alpha \rangle\\
    & = j \langle j, \beta | j, \alpha \rangle = j \delta_{\alpha \beta}.
\end{align*}
Note the critical step where he writes $J^+ J^- = [J^+, J^-]$.
It makes sense right now, but it's the basis for my question
later. Define $N_j(\alpha) = \sqrt{j} =: N_j$. Then
we also have
\begin{align*}
    J^+ | j - 1, \alpha \rangle & = \frac{1}{N_j} J^+ J^- | j, \alpha \rangle\\
    & = \frac{1}{N_j} [J^+, J^-] | j, \alpha \rangle\\
    & = \frac{j}{N_j} |j, \alpha \rangle = N_j | j, \alpha \rangle.
\end{align*}
Georgi then goes on to say something that I don't understand
at all:

"Now an analogous argument shows that there are orthonormal
states $|j - 2, \alpha \rangle$ satisfying$\ldots$",

where he then writes the normal raising/lowering operator relations.
The reason why this isn't clear to me is that I don't
see how you can use $J^+ J^- = [J^+, J^-]$ for states
without the highest $j$ values, e.g. $|j - 1, \alpha \rangle$.
Previously, it made sense, as $J^- J^+ | j, \alpha \rangle = 0$,
as per our previous definition. I do not see how this holds
on $|j - 1, \alpha \rangle$, or any other state that's not
$|j, \alpha \rangle$. What is he doing here? Is he simply
redefining the highest $j$ state every time he does this process,
or is my initial reasoning for why $J^+ J^- = [J^+, J^-]$ incorrect?

From the commutation relations of the SU(2) algebra we get
$$J_3 J^\pm  | m,\alpha \rangle = J^\pm J_3 | m,\alpha \rangle \pm J^\pm | m,\alpha \rangle = (m \pm 1) J^\pm | m,\alpha \rangle.$$
This means $m\pm 1$ is the $J_3$ eigenvalue of state $J^\pm | m,\alpha \rangle$ for all $m$.
The key insight is that this is equivalent to $J^\pm | m,\alpha \rangle = N^\pm_m(\alpha) | m\pm 1,\alpha' \rangle$, for some normalization $N^\pm_m$ and some possibly different $\alpha'$. By having a largest $J_3$ eigenvalue $j$, $N_j^+(\alpha) = 0.$
For the highest eigenvalue state, you calculate
$$
\langle j,\beta' | J^+ J^- | j,\alpha' \rangle = \langle j, \beta' | \left[ J^+, J^- \right] | j,\alpha' \rangle,
$$
which is true because $J^-J^+ | j,\alpha' \rangle = 0$, and you use this to calculate $N^+_{j-1}(\alpha) = N^-_j(\alpha) = \sqrt{j}$.
For eigenvalue $j-k$, to calculate $N^+_{j-k-1}(\alpha)$ and $N^-_{j-k}(\alpha)$, you calculate
$$
\langle j-k,\beta' | J^+ J^- | j-k,\alpha' \rangle = \langle j-k, \beta' | \left( \left[ J^+, J^- \right] + J^- J^+\right)| j-k,\alpha' \rangle,
$$
where now the second term doesn't vanish, but does have an expression in terms of your results for eigenvalue $j-k+1$ via
$$
J^+ | j-k, \alpha' \rangle = N^+_{j-k}(\alpha') |j-k+1, \alpha' \rangle.
$$
This is the sense in which you induct on weights $m$, and in each step you prove that $J^\pm$ does not change $\alpha$ and has eigenvalue $N_m$ independent of $\alpha$, and you can solve for each $N_m$. Which is what Georgi does on page 19 in equations III.9 and III.10d.
